# ¿Como solucionar error 403 al subir archivo mediante Ajax? (Nombre con comilla)

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, .htaccess

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, he desarrollado un modulo para subir archivos mediante ajax + jquery + laravel 5.1, el problema que tengo se presenta cuando intento subir un archivo con comilla simple dentro de su nombre , ejemplo: nombre de mi archivo mexico´s.pdf.
Al ejecutar el proceso localmente (en mi pc) no presento el problema, el conflicto se presenta cuando intento realizarlo en mi sitio de producción (hosting compartido).

error:

> Request URL:http://****/upload
>
> Request Method:POST
>
> Status Code:403 Forbidden

Comment: Al ser un error  403, parece mas problema de permisos que de nombre. Has comprobado que tengas permiso de lectura y escritura?

Comment: Si así es, la carpeta donde se almacenan los archivos tiene los permisos necesarios, cuando subimos un archivo sin alguna comilla simple en el nombre no existe problema.
El conflicto lo presenta la comilla simple '

Comment: Prueba a renombrar el fichero en la subida, a ver si así te funciona

Comment: El error permanece si dejo la comilla simple " ' ", si elimino la comilla, el archivo sube sin problemas.

Comment: Al parecer es un conflicto que existe con el modulo mod_security de mi servidor web, alguna idea para implementarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta va a tratar dos tópicos: 1. La posible solución al asunto de la comilla, que es generalizable al uso de caracteres "especiales" y 2. El terrible agujero de seguridad que creas en tu sitio de producción a consecuencia de tu manejo de nombres de archivo.

1. Muchos sistemas operativos (en especial dela familia unix-linux) restringen la creación de nombres de archivo y directorios a un juego de caracteres limitado a letras, números, guiones, puntos, espacios y rechazan caracteres como comillas letras con acentos etc.
   Algunos marcan con punto inicial o moños los archivos ocultos. De modo que, si puedes crear (subir y guardar) el archivo sin comilla, cabe esperar que tu hosting te imponga esa limitación.
2. El uso de nombres tal como son recogidos por $_FILES está totalmente desaconsejado por razones de seguridad como las siguientes:

   - Las validaciones usando extensiones, son sólo funcionales, cualquiera puede cambiar una extensión y ofrecer un archivo malicioso con extensión cambiada.
   - Adicionalmente, si el nombre contiene juegos de puntos y separadores puede provocar un "movimiento" dentro del sistema de directorios y reemplazar archivos sensibles o ir a parar a un directorio en el que pueda ser ejecutado.
   - Por otra parte, supongamos un ataque "ingenuo" que no busca hacer daño al sistema, ni siquiera hacer intrusión: Te ponen a alojar pornografía o warez o información social o políticamente peligrosa, y como conocen los nombres de archivo, saben qué paths ofrecer a sus futuros usuarios o contactos.

Hay más, pero no se justifica extenderse, por ahora. Dejo este ejemplo a una respuesta para que se vea un ataque grave [Un ataque de borrado de base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113672/91033)

De todo esto se desprende que NUNCA se deben usar los nombres de archivo ofrecidos por los usuarios; es MALA PRÁCTICA hacerlo (perdón los gritos) y se deben guardar como metadata o como información complementaria a los registros de los nombres con que sean guardados.
Los archivos que suban al servidor deben guardarse usando nombres pseudoaleatorios y seguros, con permiso de sólo lectura, en directorios sin permiso de ejecución.