# Problema al subir archivos al servidor

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, upload, fileupload

Cree un carpeta llamada archivos `www.MiServidor.com/Archivos` a la cual le modifique los permisos para poder leer, escribir y modificar. Tengo un formulario en el `index.php` en el que se inserta un nombre de una imagen y un archivo. Al enviar el formulario ejecuta un archivo `PHP` el cual recibe dos `POST` y realiza una inserción a una tabla aquí paso el codigo.

```
include("../Conexion.php");
$Conexion = new Conexion(SERVIDOR,USUARIO,PASS,DB); //inicializo la base de datos
session_start(); 
$Nombre = $_POST["Nombre"]; //recibo el nombre de la imagen
$imagen = $_FILES["Imagen" ]; //recibo la imagen

$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,".$url.",'".$Nombre."')"; //Inserto un registro con el nombre y la url
$Conexion -> set_charset('utf8');
$Conexion->query($archi);
```

Hasta aqui todo funciona bien, después intento almacenar el archivo recibido en la carpeta `Archivos` que cree en el servidor con la siguiente linea

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ $name ][ 'tmp_name' ], 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Archivos/".$nombre);
```

pero no almacena nada, sin embargo en mi servidor local `localhost` si me lo permite, pero en mi servidor rentado (Neubox.com) no me permite

NOTA: solo subo imagenes png

a continuación le comparto el código

```
include("../Conexion.php"); //incluyo la conexion

$Conexion = new Conexion(SERVIDOR,USUARIO,PASS,DB); //inicializo la base de datos
session_start(); 
$Nombre = $_POST["Nombre"]; //recibo el nombre de la imagen
$imagen = $_FILES["Imagen" ]; //recibo la imagen

$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,".$url.",'".$Nombre."')"; //Inserto un registro con el nombre y la url
$Conexion -> set_charset('utf8');
$Conexion->query($archi);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ $name ][ 'tmp_name' ], 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Archivos/".$nombre.".png");
```

Sin embargo no me marca ningún tipo de error, simplemente no almacena nada.

Answer (score 2):

**Preludio: tu código tiene un hoyo gigante de seguridad que explico más abajo.**

Primero, tu variable `$url` no está definida. Luego si el nombre que elegiste es "perrito":

```
$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,".$url.",'".$Nombre."')";
```

Se traduce en

```
$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,,'perrito')";
```

La doble coma lo hace una sentencia inválida y nada se inserta. Digamos entonces que `$url` sería:

```
$url = '/Archivos/'.$Nombre.'.png';
```

Supongamos que tu front dice algo como

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="subir.php" method="POST">
    Elija un nombre para el archivo: 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" value=""  />
    Elija un archivo desde su computadora:
    <input type="file" name="imagen"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar archivo" />
</form>
```

El contenido de `subir.php` sería (ojo que estoy definiendo `$url` que tú no tienes definido);

```
include("../Conexion.php"); //incluyo la conexion
$Conexion = new Conexion(SERVIDOR,USUARIO,PASS,DB);
session_start(); 
$Nombre = $_POST["nombre"]; //recibo el nombre de la imagen
$imagen = $_FILES["imagen" ]; //recibo la imagen

$url = '/Archivos/'.$Nombre.'.png';

$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,'$url','$Nombre')"; 

$Conexion->set_charset('utf8');
$Conexion->query($archi);

move_uploaded_file($imagen[ 'tmp_name' ], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Archivos/$Nombre.png");
```

Y esto "funcionaría".

Ahora imagínate que yo elijo que mi archivo ($Nombre) se llame

```
"perrito'); DROP TABLE Archivos;--";
```

Tu consulta `$archi' se transformaría en

```
INSERT INTO Archivo VALUES (null, '/Archivos/perrito.png','perrito'); DROP TABLE Archivos;--
```

¿Te das cuenta de que interpolando directamente el valor del campo $Nombre estás llamando a una catástrofe?

La manera correcta sería algo como:

```
$archi = "INSERT INTO Archivos VALUES (null,:url,:nombre)"; 
$stmt = $Conexion->prepare($archi);
$stmt->bindParam(':url', $url, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':nombre', $Nombre, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comic Tax:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

no subes nada por que no le estas diciendo que archivo subir.

parece ser que el problema es: $_FILES[**$name**]['tmp_name'] la variable **$name** no veo donde está definida en tu script php, tampoco veo donde está definida la variable **$nombre**.

$nombre y $Nombre no son lo mismo.

pon algo como esto:

```
$archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['temp_name'];
$nombrearchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

move_uploaded_file($archivo, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Archivos/'.$nombrearchivo);
```

debes asegurarte de que la dirección donde estás subiendo el archivo en tu servidor sea correcto y que los nombres de los campos de tu formulario concuerden con los de tu script php.

también puedes ver la documentación en el sitio de php.

http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, pero el problema lo resolvimos aumentando el tiempo de respuesta en el servidor y el ancho de banda de transferencia en el servidor, el código no se modifico!!!